# When pushing values into an array from a while loop that is inside a `for` loop, it overwrites the previous elements in the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, for-loop, while-loop

> When I push values into an array from a while loop inside that's for loop it overwrites the previous elements inside the array.

```
        var startDate = new Date(theoreticalData[0].UpdateDateMDY);
        var newDate = startDate;
        var daysDif = 0;
        var daysArray = [startDate];
        for ( var i= 1; i<theoreticalData.length; i++ ) {                
            var OldCycle = parseInt(theoreticalData[i].OldCycle);
            daysDif = theoreticalData[i].DaysDifference;
            while (daysDif > OldCycle ) {
                nextDate = this.sumDays(nextDate , OldCycle);
                daysArray.push(nextDate);
                daysDif = daysDif - OldCycle;
            } 
            nextDate = this.sumDays(nextDate , daysDif);
            daysArray.push(nextDate);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I push values inside a while loop inside a for loop it overwrites
>   the previous elements inside the array.

Because you are updating the same object everytime and pushing it to the array,

change this line

```
nextDate = this.sumDays(nextDate , OldCycle);
```

to

```
nextDate = new Date(this.sumDays(nextDate , OldCycle).getTime());
```

This will create a new **Date** object everytime.

Comment: @LaiaChorroYanguas please upvote and accept the right answer that helped you https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I have noticed now that the last value of my array is always duplicated, why is this happening?

Comment: @LaiaChorroYanguas you need to do this outside while loop as well

Comment: I thought this would fix it!

Comment: @gurvinder372 I have applied this everywhere in the code but is duplicating some elements at the end of the array don't know why.